# Find tag name of pyquery object

Tags: python, object, tags, pyquery

```
for l in d.items('nl,de,en'):
   if l.tag()=='nl':
      dothis()
```

How can I find the tag associated with a pyquery object? The method tag() in 
the exaple above doesnt exist...

Comment: I think I got it : l[0].tag ....

Answer (score 2):

The right way to get the tag name is with `is_()` function.

```
for l in d.items('nl,de,en'):
   if l.is_('nl')
      dothis()
```

from the docs:
[https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/*modules/pyquery/pyquery.html#PyQuery.is*](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/_modules/pyquery/pyquery.html#PyQuery.is_)

Hope it helped.